# SELECT if exists where DATE=TODAY, if not where DATE=YESTERDAY

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with some columns and a date column (that i made a partition with)
For example

```
[Amount, Date    ]  
[4     , 2020-4-1]  
[3     , 2020-4-2]  
[5     , 2020-4-4]
```

I want to get the latest Amount based on the Date.

I thought about doing a `LIMIT 1` with `ORDER BY`, but, is that optimized by BigQuery or it will scan my entire table?

I want to avoid costs at all possible, I thought about doing a query based on the date today, and if nothing found search for yesterday, but I don't know how to do it in only one query.

Comment: I have some questions: 
1) If you have more than one value in the last date, do you want to get all that values? 
2) About the mentioned approach at the end of your question: will you always have some value for today or yesterday? Will the "search for some data today and if it doesn't exists search for some data yesterday" approach work for you?

Comment: 1)nope, only 1 of them, no chance there is more than 1 value though     2)It's very rare for the data to not be yesterday, so i can return 0 rows in that case

Comment: Posted a possible solution for you. I hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `date` field is a partition, you can use it in `WHERE` clause to filter which partitions should be read in your query.

In your case, you could do something like:

```
SELECT value
FROM <your-table>
WHERE Date >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
ORDER BY Data DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This query basically will:

1. Filter only today's and yesterday's partitions
2. Order the rows by your Date field, from the most recent to the older
3. Select the first element of the ordered list

If the table has a row with today's date, the query will return the data for today. If it dont't, the query will return the data for yesterday.

Finally, I would like to attach here this [reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables) regarding querying partitioned tables.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(amount ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)]
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE `date` >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Note: above assumes your `date` field is of DATE data type.

Comment: what is the SAFE_OFFSET doing there?

Comment: SAFE_OFFSET makes sure that even if array is empty and there is no first element - it will not fail but rather return null. Because of WHERE clause I thought it will be extra precocious to avoid error. but it might be that just simple OFFSET in this case will also work

Comment: This does what i want, but, will this scan the entire db or just some partitions?

Comment: if your table is not partitioned by `date` field - it will scan involved columns in all rows. meantime - if it does what you wanted - consider voting up the answer and accept it :o)

Comment: Even so you gave the correct answer initially i found rmesteves answer more complete. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The LIMIT order stops the query whet it gets the amount of results indicated.
I think the query should be something like this, I'm not sure if "today()-1" returns

```
SELECT Amount
FROM <table> as t
WHERE date(t.Date) = current_date()
OR date(t.Date) = makedate(year(current_date()), dayofyear(current_date())-1);
```

Edited: Sorry, my answer is for MariaDB I now see you ask for Google-BigQuery which I didn't even know, but it looks like SQL, I hope it has some functions like the ones I posted.